# Private and protected works on child class. and what is polymophism

Tags: php, class, oop, polymorphism, private

> ```
> <?php
> class main{
>   public $bob="my name bob";
>   private $lee="my surname lee";
>   protected $david="my caste";
>        function output(){
>   $output=$this->lee;
>    echo $output;
> }
> } class second extends main{ } $obj= new second; $obj->output();
>
> ?>
> ```

the output is 'my surname lee'.
how ? i am confused with private and protected.please let me understand the working of it.and what is polymorphism in php any tutorial link or example.

Comment: No, the output is "my surname lee": https://eval.in/103895

Comment: the output is "my surname lee" : http://codepad.org/Ky2XOZJr then what do you need from the code?

Comment: sorry .. i mistake .the output in updated in question.but how it workis my making object of chld class.
$obj= new second; 
$obj->output();

Comment: the $lee is private ..so how it works..what the functionality of private and protected in this code.

Comment: @user3334006 $lee is private. it couldnt access outside of class. But the functions inside the class can accessible this $lee variable if the function has in Public scope.

Comment: thanks @ Vasu. But the problem is,i guess the private and protected works only on the same class but it works on child as well.so what the importance of it.any link of tutorial which let me understand the fuctionality.thanks once again.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[polymorphism in php](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-and-applying-polymorphism-in-php--net-14362) is well explained here.

In one word:
Polymorphism describes a pattern in object oriented programming in which classes have different functionality while sharing a common interface.

For your question: However the variable

```
$lee
```

is private, the function

```
function output()
```

is public and can be accessed outside.

And this [page](https://www.php.net/protected) have more specific sinariao in the php programming language.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.. and what is the problem in above code.

Comment: [Visibility](http://cn2.php.net/protected) look at this page. the function is public, it can be access outside.